# Merge function and stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPViewMTO] 
AS
BEGIN


select *,round((Quantity-(QuantityBeforeDone+QuantityExistInSite+QuantitySpool+TotalMIV)),3) As Shortage,CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(int,SheetNumber))+'/'+ CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int,TotalSheet)) As NewSheetNumber

  from(
SELECT      *
           ,isnull(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Warehouse
           ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as totalIMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMRC

,isnull(dbo.ReturnMIVNumberAndQuantity(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as MIVs

 from dbo.ViewMTO
 )a

END
```

And this function :

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnMIVNumberAndQuantity](@lineId int,@testpackId int,@matdesId int )
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 


SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + MaterialIssueVouchers.Code+'['+convert(nvarchar,MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.QuantityDeliver)+']'  from (MaterialIssueVouchers inner join
               MaterialIssueVoucherDetails on 
               MaterialIssueVouchers.Id=MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialIssueVoucherId)inner join MaterialRequestContractorDetails on MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialRequestContractorDetailId=MaterialRequestContractorDetails.Id
               where MaterialRequestContractorDetails.TestPackageId=@testpackId  and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.LineId=@lineId and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.MaterialDescriptionId=@matdesId

    RETURN @Names
END
```

As you can see this function is called in the stored procedure, because of the speed of query I want to add the function to the stored procedure.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPViewMTO] 
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
select *,round((Quantity-(QuantityBeforeDone+QuantityExistInSite+QuantitySpool+TotalMIV)),3) As Shortage,CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(int,SheetNumber))+'/'+ CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int,TotalSheet)) As NewSheetNumber

  from(
SELECT      *
           ,isnull(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Warehouse
           ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as totalIMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMRC

,(SELECT COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + MaterialIssueVouchers.Code+'['+convert(nvarchar,MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.QuantityDeliver)+']'  from (MaterialIssueVouchers inner join
               MaterialIssueVoucherDetails on 
               MaterialIssueVouchers.Id=MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialIssueVoucherId)inner join MaterialRequestContractorDetails on MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialRequestContractorDetailId=MaterialRequestContractorDetails.Id
               where MaterialRequestContractorDetails.TestPackageId=TestPackageId  and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.LineId=LineId and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.MaterialDescriptionId=ViewMTO.MaterialDescriptionId) as MIVs

 from dbo.ViewMTO
 )a

    END
```

**Try another approach**

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPViewMTO] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

    SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + MaterialIssueVouchers.Code+'['+convert(nvarchar,MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.QuantityDeliver)+']'  from (MaterialIssueVouchers inner join
    MaterialIssueVoucherDetails on 
    MaterialIssueVouchers.Id=MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialIssueVoucherId)inner join MaterialRequestContractorDetails on MaterialIssueVoucherDetails.MaterialRequestContractorDetailId=MaterialRequestContractorDetails.Id
    where MaterialRequestContractorDetails.TestPackageId=@testpackId  and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.LineId=@lineId and MaterialRequestContractorDetails.MaterialDescriptionId=@matdesId


    select *,round((Quantity-(QuantityBeforeDone+QuantityExistInSite+QuantitySpool+TotalMIV)),3) As Shortage,CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(int,SheetNumber))+'/'+ CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(int,TotalSheet)) As NewSheetNumber

    from(
    SELECT      *
    ,isnull(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Warehouse
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as totalIMIV
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMIV
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMRC

    ,isnull(@Names),0) as MIVs

    from dbo.ViewMTO
    )a

END
```

Comment: I get this error :Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: plz Execute only the sub-query that exists into ISNULL function, is it retrieve more than one value or not ??

Comment: No it just return one value

Comment: So the merge is okay , Now there is a sub-query returns more than one, Execute each one at separate to get which one raised the error.

Comment: This part should like this @names=COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '')

Comment: But it returns error when i changed to @names=COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '')

Comment: Try another approach, into my answer.

Comment: Lots of error :Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@testpackId".
Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: Now there is a sub-query returns more than one, Execute each one at separate to get which one raised the error